# designing simple load test of data inserts on multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am testing a database stored procedure and related EF code doing inserts on multiple threads. I have this code below that selects N # of rows into a List and then loops that N count to perform inserts. I want each call to ExecuteCaseLogInsert to run on a separate thread.

```
public void InsertCaseLog(int rowsToInsert)
        {
            //select top x # of rows from existing case logs and loop those rows to insert case log records.
            WWLabContext context = new WWLabContext();
            List<PaacsCaseLog> data = (from c in context.PaacsCaseLog
                        select c).Take(rowsToInsert).ToList();

            //loop for the rows requested to be inserted
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsToInsert; i++)
            {
                PaacsCaseLog row = new PaacsCaseLog();
                row = data[i];
                //start a new thread
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteCaseLogInsert(row));
                t.Start();
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteCaseLogInsert(PaacsCaseLog data)
        {
            string strCaseId = "";
            WWLPoC.dsPaacs.CaseLogInsertUpdate(ref strCaseId, data.SiteId.GetValueOrDefault(), data.FirstName, data.Surname, data.Middle1, data.PostOporders);
        }
```

I am getting a compile error at

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteCaseLogInsert(row));
```

in the ThreadStart method of "Method name expected".

1. Does this code look correct for what I am trying to do?
2. Why would my method name be rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

1. You don't want a `ThreadStart` delegate; what you want is a `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate.
2. You pass, as the error message mentions, the method group (name), not a method call (which is what you have).
3. Your receiving method `ExecuteCaseLogInsert` will need to change its parameter to type `object` and you'll have to cast it to what you want in the method.

**OR**

Don't use raw threads, use Task Parallel Library (TPL):

1. Instead of your `for` loop, use

   ```
   Parallel.For(0, rowsToInsert, i =>
   {
       PaacsCaseLog row = new PaacsCaseLog();
       row = data[i];
       ExecuteCaseLogInsert(row);
   }
   ```